# How to create exe file from a office.js add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, exe, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I created an officeJs add-in using Yeoman generator.
Microsoft add-in documentation mentioned many ways to publish an add-in, but I need to build a .exe file of my add-in. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Office web add-ins act like a web site which is loaded into an embedded web browser in Office applications or regular web browsers in case of Office365. You can't really use any executables in this scenario for security reasons.

If you need to create an executable file with your add-in you may consider creating a VSTO add-in which can be run on Windows only and support only the desktop editions of MS Office. See [Get started programming VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) for more information.